# Return first N characters of string

Tags: sql-server, string

I need to select a shortened version of a field from a SQL Server table to use in a drop down list.

This field has to be limited to twenty characters.  If the field has more than twenty characters, it should display the first twenty; if it has less than twenty characters, it should display the whole string.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 22):

Try `left(sting_field,20)` or `right(sting_field,20)`

Comment: with this if the string length is say 10, will the new string be only 10 or 10 + 10 spaces?

Answer (score 4):

This SELECT should do:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(ISNULL(stringfield, ''), 1, 20)
```

It will replace a "NULL" value with an empty string '' and limit length to 20 chars max.

Comment: Isn't LEFT() better than SUBSTRING()?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933238(SQL.80).aspx) command.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused... why dont you have the code that populates the dropdown manage the length of the data being loaded.

If you must do it within a query you could simply do a substring on the column:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql